# I run clamav and throws me: error: getcwd() failed with errno 2/No such file or directory

Tags: clamav

I compile the latest version of clamav from source.

And by executing the following command

sudo clamscan --infected --recursive /home

In the end it throws me the following error

error: getcwd() failed with errno 2/No such file or directory

error: Could not determine current working directory. Is your locale set correctly?

How can I solve that?

I've read that  getcwd is = get the pathname of the current working directory.

I think I am missing a directory, but I don't know what it is.

I would like to fully understand why the above happens

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------

Known viruses: 8525167

Engine version: 0.103.2

Scanned directories: 14538

Scanned files: 388293

Infected files: 0

Data scanned: 23363.42 MB

Data read: 59186.47 MB (ratio 0.39:1)

Time: 2491.630 sec (41 m 31 s)

Start Date: 2021:05:02 13:04:16

End Date:   2021:05:02 13:45:47

error: getcwd() failed with errno 2/No such file or directory

error: Could not determine current working directory. Is your locale set correctly?

Comment: SOLVED :D..................

Comment: Please feel free to post the solution as an answer.